# Having a hard time getting the Angular CLI server to start

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I'm sure this isn't the first time you've run into this issue. I've researched over google, youtube, and stackoverflow on this issue, and it seems like this is an isolated incident. I don't know if it's an issue with versions, but I have been taking the Pluralsight course on Angular with Deborah K. I downloaded her Github version of the boilerplate starting files from https://github.com/DEborahK/Angular-GEttingStarted

I followed the course and installed the dependences from the package.json file using the integrated terminal. When I tried to run the script npm start which translates into `ng serve -o` I get this error message:

> apm@0.0.0 start /Users/mateo/Desktop/projects/angular
>
> ng serve -o
>
> Cannot read property 'config' of null
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of null
>       at Class.run (/Users/mateo/Desktop/projects/angular/node_modules/@angular/cli/tasks/serve.js:21:63)
>       at check_port_1.checkPort.then.port (/Users/mateo/Desktop/projects/angular/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/serve.js:110:26)
>       at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:118:7)
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! errno 1
>
> npm ERR! apm@0.0.0 start: `ng serve -o`
>
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the apm@0.0.0 start script.
>
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!     /Users/mateo/.npm/_logs/2018-03-26T22_16_46_516Z-debug.log
>
> Sandys-MacBook-Pro:angular mateo$

Is there a best practice way to troubleshoot these kind of issues? Is there a better way to run these scripts or should I use a sandbox VMware linux install to run these fresh instead of running off my Macbook? Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: I would recommend going to the Angular page and downloading the latest version, then continuing the tutorial.  If it's covering the basics, I suspect that you won't see any deviations from her tutorial code.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this issue by deleting all of the node_modules and re-installing the AngularCLI from scratch off of the Angular website.